# Need to convert string of certain type to Date for all browser

Tags: jquery, firefox, date, safari

I have a String `2011-10-10` which needs to be converted to a Date object.

```
var myDate = new Date('2011-10-10')
```

is fine on FF but not Safari.

What is a good way to ensure I can convert this String to Date on Safari?

I have JQuery but can see an appropriate API.

Note: When I have created the Date object I want to then convert to UTC format which I will do by doing

```
myDate.toUTCString()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

return Date object:

```
var myDate = new Date(Date.parse('2013-01-01'));
```

Comment: Still returns undefined on safari

Answer (score 0):

The date parsing behavior on JavaScript is implementation-dependent, the ISO8601 format was recently added to the ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification, but this is not yet supported by all implementations.

I would recommend you to parse it manually, for example:

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);
}

parseDate('2011-01-03'); // Mon Jan 03 2011 00:00:00
```

Basically the above function matches each date part and uses the Date constructor, to build a date object, note that the months argument needs to be 0-based (0=Jan, 1=Feb,...11=Dec).